# Batch rename or batch reset of all material node label

Tags: python

How to rename the label of a node with specific string?

Or it is if reset the label of all materials in the scene.

2nd one can we batch rename one material name with specific string.

Answer (score 3):

To batch rename, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. You can choose to rename ***All*** or ***Selected*** and whatever type of data-block you want to rename.

[image]

You can change the *Batch Rename* method to ***New*** name, add a ***Prefix*** or ***Suffix***, and even stack layers of renaming functionality.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jakemoyo, but I need a python script to change node label of materials, objects & material name with some string replaced one new one...

Comment: Have you tried anything yet or are you just expecting someone to write a script for you?

Comment: No sir I tried by seeing a post in other site. I don't much about python script. But I need a python script to change node label of materials, objects & material name with some string replaced one new one... e.g. floor_base_1, floor_base_2 floor_base_3 etc with name floor_mat_1, floor_mat_2 floor_mat_3 etc. I need this renaming system for all objects, materials & node labels of scene...

Comment: You should be able to do all of this with the batch rename function.

Comment: Can you give a script for me..?

Comment: @RadhakrishnaRao [here](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1fkRtMmJ4OOrY20bOVlxn_PFYx9ly97j)